# maven: how to build the dependency from source.jar to jar files and put the jar file as it dependency?

Tags: java, maven, jar

For maven 3, I need to use the

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

as the one of my dependency, but I only can find the source jar form maven central:

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/sql/jdbc-stdext/2.0/

how to compile it as normal jar in maven with maven plugins and make it work as one of dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add another Maven repository to your Pom.xml and get jdbc-stdext-2.0.jar
http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-releases/javax/sql/jdbc-stdext/2.0/

```
<repository>
    <id>jfrog-libs</id>
    <name>jfrog-libs</name>
    <url>http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-releases</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

Comment: why import libraries when the classes are included in the standard Java installation? I think it has a reason why the jar of executable code isn't provided in the standard repository.

Comment: Yes, don't need if the JDK has it.  But for projects depending on older JDK versions, I think this answer may help.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article: [Maven central is missing jars for transitive dependencies](https://github.com/Mozu/mozu-integrations-template/issues/7)

So I downloaded the sources.jar of jdbc-stdext and looked inside. The classes `DataSource`, `ConnectionEvent` and `PooledConnection` are included in standard libraries of Java 8. So you don't need tom import the dependency via maven.

**Edit:** If the artifact `jdbc-stdext` is needed as a transitive dependency, you can prevent maven from trying to fetch it by this way:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.xy</groupId>
    <artifactId>libA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
             <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
             <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```